# Unit Testing Swagger Output

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-5, swagger, swashbuckle

We are using Swashbuckle to generate the swagger output for the REST endpoints of our MVC api application. I'm wondering what options there are for unit testing the swagger in a test project. I want to verify things like method names, descriptions, parameters etc etc to minimize the possibility that breaking changes can be introduced.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Please try [Swagger-Codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen), which is a free an open source project to automatically generate API clients, server stubs and API documnetation.

For the C# API client generated by Swagger Codegen, it comes with test files for unit testing and you can update it to detect breaking changes by reusing the same tests after updating the OpenAPI/Swagger Spec files.